# How to stop fscanf from copying into array when its at the end of the line?

Tags: c

I have a file that has lines like

```
Bob, 2,3,13,4
Jim 3,4,15,3
...
```

and I'm trying to copy into my numbers array only the integers in each line, so that i I could do some math with them.

Problem is, I don't know before hand how many numbers there will be after the name of the person, but I know it will be less than 100. However, when I run my code, it copies 2,3,13,4 into my array and then assigns a bunch of random numbers into the other slots of the array. How do I get around this?

I want it to stop copying after it sees a carriage return, and I tried to do that by doing an if statement like if (fgetc=!'\r') but it doesn't work, nor does it work with '\n'. Can someone help me out of this problem?

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
FILE *myFile;
myFile = fopen("bob.txt", "r");

//read file into array
int numberArray[100];
int i;

if (myFile == NULL)
{
printf("Error Reading File\n");
exit (0);
}

int k=0;
while(k==0){
if(fgetc(myFile)==',')
k=1;
} //brings pointer to the first number after the first comma
//still need a way to stop copying into array random numbers after the line is done
//so need it to stop after carriage return, but it doesn't work
//also need to start it again after for the next line

for (i = 0; i <100 ; i++)
{
fscanf(myFile, "%d,", &numberArray[i])
}

for (i = 0; i < 100 ; i++)
{
printf("Number is: %d\n\n", numberArray[i]);
}

fclose(myFile);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question in multiple SE sites.  Your question [How to stop copying into array using fscanf when its end of the line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962500/how-to-stop-copying-into-array-using-fscanf-when-its-the-end-of-the-line?noredirect=1) was migrated from [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), and it was fortunate that I spotted it before it was given answers (so it could be cleanly closed as a duplicate of this).

Comment: `int numberArray[100] = { 0 };` will initialize your array to all zeroes.  It sounds like you are printing out some unitialized values. At least this will help you see where you stopped adding numbers to your array.

Answer (score 1):

`fscanf` will return the number of items scanned; in your situation, as soon as it returns 0, you know you are done with that line (because it couldn't scan an integer).

Comment: In general, though, you can't make `fscanf()` recognize line endings; you can't insist on an array having 5 entries per line (for sake of example) unless you read the lines with `fgets()` or `getline()` (from POSIX 2008), and then use `sscanf()` to parse the line.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong tool for the job trying to read text that has a special line format.

Although it is *possible* to do this with `fscanf()`, it is far easier to handle bad input with `fgets()`.  Use `sscanf()` with `"%n"` (or `strtol()`) to parse each line.

It appears a comma is optional between elements given OP's 2 examples.

```
char name[40];
char buf[sizeof name + 100*22 + 2];
// read the entire line
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, myFile) == NULL) Handle_EOF();

int n;
char *p = buf;
// Get the name
if (sscanf(p, "%39[A-Za-z] %n", name, &n) != 1) Handle_NoName();
p += n;

// Get the integers
for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
  if (*p == ',') p++;
  if (sscanf(p, "%d %n", &numberArray[i], &n) != 1) break;
  p += n;
}

// Initialize remaining elements
for (; i<100; i++) {
  numberArray[i] = 0;
}

if (*p) Hanlde_ExtraTextAtEndOfLine();

// Use name and numberArray[] with i elements.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int numberArray[100];
int i, ch, n;

while(1){
    while((ch=fgetc(myFile))!=EOF && ch != ',')
        ;//skip name and ','
    if(ch == EOF)
        break;
    //check of the end of the line is not necessary if name do not begin with a digit.
    for (i = 0; i < 100 && 1==fscanf(myFile, "%d,", &numberArray[i]); i++)
        ;

    n = i;
    for (i = 0; i < n ; i++){
        printf("Number is: %d\n", numberArray[i]);
    }
}
```